# Angular query params when refreshing Page

Tags: angular, angular-router-params

I have an issue, that is struggling me.
Scenario - Page A and Page B:

- In Page A I have a button that navigate to Page B adding a query params

```
this.router.navigate(['asignaturas', 2, 'datosgenerales'], {queryParams: {edit: false}});
```

- Page B is loaded correctly. BUT if I click refresh in browser i got an error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'asignaturas/2/datosgenerales%3Fedit%3Dfalse'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'asignaturas/2/datosgenerales%3Fedit%3Dfalse'
```

The URL is adding the query params also. That I wouldn't like to.

- I tried to check when is page reload with this code and recreate the navigation

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.browserRefresh = browserRefresh; // Give true | false if is page refresh
    if(this.browserRefresh) {
      this.router.navigate(['asignaturas/2/datosgenerales'], {queryParams: {edit: true}});
    }
```

Even trying to recreate the url, it still throw me the error.
It there a way to fix it, or ignore the query params

Comment: have you tried `queryParamsHandling: "preserve"`

Comment: Yes, It causes same error :(

Comment: I think you must share you url of the moment while navigating to page B and after reload once. Also routes array.